# Alternative to 'quit' command

Tags: applescript

I know the question title looks weird so I'll try to explain it better: I know you can make applications quit by doing this:

```
tell application "whatever" to quit
```

I want to know if there are any alternatives to doing this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Antal S-Z I'm guessing the OP just wants to learn more about AppleScript.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `GUI Scripting` like this...

```
tell application "System Events" to tell process "whatever" to keystroke "q" using {command down}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the `tell application "whatever" to quit` approach is that you can only target applications that are installed on your machine upon compilation of the script. Here's an AppleScript that determines the names of all running application processes and then quits each one by sending it the `quit` command.

```
property pExcludeApps : {"Finder", name of current application}

tell application "System Events"
    set theAppsToQuit to name of every process where background only = false
end tell

repeat with theApp in theAppsToQuit
    if pExcludeApps does not contain contents of theApp then
        tell application (contents of theApp)
            quit saving yes
        end tell
    end if
end repeat
```

Answer (score 1):

```
delay 5
tell application (path to frontmost application as text) to quit saving no
```

---

```
delay 5
tell application "System Events" to set pid to unix id of (process 1 where frontmost is true)
do shell script "kill " & pid
```

---

```
tell application "TextEdit" to close windows
tell application "System Events" to tell process "TextEdit" to set visible to false
-- Lion will auto-terminate the app
```